# Customizing TFS 2012 Process Template and how it affects reports

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

If I use one of the three Process Templates that ships with TFS 2012, (add a new work item type or a new transition, etc), will the TFS reporting and web site information incorporate the new customizations?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Are you altering an existing Team Project, or creating a new one? What do you mean by "web site information"? Web Access?

Comment: The customization would be for a new Team Project.   The website is the website that TFS provides for the Team Project.

Answer (score 0):

The SSRS reports and certain parts of Web Access are defined by which process template you choose, so yes they will be sync'ed.